# Fields as Doc_Values to drop Memory Usage

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

Currently we are facing a lot of exceptions like this:

```
ElasticsearchException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: Data too large, data for field [field1] would be larger than limit of [24108466176/22.4gb]]
```

After some investigation of the above exception, `field1` seems to take a lot of `fielddata cache size` along with another field let's call it `field2`

Result of `GET /_stats/fielddata?fields=field1,field2`:

```
"total": {
         "fielddata": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 260456614595,
            "evictions": 1226307,
            "fields": {
               "field1": {
                  "memory_size_in_bytes": 76629429704
               },
               "field2": {
                  "memory_size_in_bytes": 97600838429
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

Note: both fields are `not_analyzed`. Field1 is used heavily in search queries while field2 not so much.

So by the [doc value](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html) section of es documentation those fields can be stored as `doc values` to reduce heap usage.

Is this a good approach to solve memory issues like the above exception?

Documentation also says that by storing fields as doc values, indexes will become larger, is there a way to calculate this increase?

Comment: Using doc-values is recommended in such situations because all the pressure that you put on the heap will be moved to disk. The downside, though, is a slight decrease in performance. And since you are moving that section of heap from memory to disk, I would guess that the increase would be similar with the decrease in heap usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Doc_Values` are awesome!

- For new indexes, `fielddata size` for those fields is at 0:

  ```
  "total": {
     "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 5394813851,
        "evictions": 112,
        "fields": {
           "field1": {
              "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
           }
        }
     }
  }
  ```
- No more `Data too large`exceptions when executing queries on those fields, not to mention that those queries execute much faster now, I guess because `CircuitBreaker` doesn't trip that often.
- For performance... a very slight decrease on indexing, nothing worrying.
- Index size, in our case, is about 20% larger now.